# Pyramid and SQL Sqlalchemy, self-referential join with additional conditions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a pyramid application using SQL Alchemy, and I have the following model:

```
class Node(Base, Auditable):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    active = Column(Boolean)
    children = relationship("Node",
                            backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
                            )
```

And I wanted to change the `children` relationship to only show those with `active == True`, how would I go about doing so?

I understand this is normally achieved using the primaryjoin option on the relationship, which makes if the two tables are different, but I don't know how you would specify which 'side' of the join the `active == True` when both sides use the same table.